# What is the brand of outdoor spigot?

Tags: spigot

I need to identify the brand of this spigot in order to replace the vacuum breaker. The spigot is about 30 yrs old.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Take it off using two wrenches, one to hold the spigot, and take it to a plumbing place to match the threads.